# Can Firefox profile load different Add-Ons depending on the computer?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-extensions

I use the same profile to use Firefox at home and work.  It's handy because all settings, saved logins, bookmarks etc... are kept in sync.

However, I'd like to skip loading some Add-Ons/Extensions while I am at home.  For instance, I would like to omit uBlock Origin at home because I have a PiHole connected to the network which already blocks ads.

How would I load Add-Ons depending on the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are already at the point where Firefox is set up on both computers and you're syncing Firefox to keep them current (rather than doing something like a portable version on a flash drive).  If so, you're almost there.

Firefox on each computer has its own profile.  Right now, they just happen to be very similar.  On each one, go into Preferences and select Firefox Account.  There, deselect syncing add-ons.  Then go to Add-ons and disable or delete the add-ons you don't want to use on that computer.  Each computer will then have the add-ons you want and everything else will remain synced.

If you're actually using the same portable version on both machines (or keeping the profile on the flash drive), please post back because there is a different solution for that.